# Powershell: How do I switch my path to a device (iphone)

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and as a exercise I am trying to write a automated script that will backup my photos of my iphone.

I am trying to figure out how to set the location of the path to my iphone photos directory.

I found the command Get-PsDrive; however, my phone name does not appear in this list.

Can anyone tell me the command(s) needed to find the phone path, and then cd to that path?

We can assume that the phone is connected.

Comment: Is the phone mounted as a drive?

Comment: Its visible from within explorer; however, it does not have a drive mapping assigned to it.

Comment: Then there is some tool providing a shell extension but not a drive.  I don't know the shell that well, but my guess would be that you would have to talk to the API of that tool (probably iTunes) if it allows it.

Answer (score 2):

This is unlikely possible without some module or snap-in that exposes iPhone files in a way that PowerShell can interpret.

For example, for *Windows Mobile* phones there is [PowerShell Windows Mobile Provider](http://psmobile.codeplex.com/).

I am not aware of something like that for iPhone (but I am not an iPhone user either). If nothing really exists then the answer is negative, this is simply not possible technically.

Comment: I assumed since I can see it in the explorer shell there must be a lower level shell interface. I'll keep looking, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol to talk to the iphone is not available for public use. The iphone icon in explorer is - as already mentioned - a windows explorer shell extension written by apple. There is no way for you to mount a drive to the iphone in the manner you wish for a stock iphone. 3rd party windows tools to access the iphone's filesystem require you install a custom application on the device, which also must be jailbroken.